# Moodle export lesson contents with images

Tags: moodle

I am trying to export Moodle lesson content from Moodle database, but I am having problems exporting images. Moodle stores lesson HTML in a MySQL database but images are referenced and need to be replaced in the HTML string.

For example. This is the source html that is saved in Moodle DB:

```
<p>
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/sound_card_zpstlml0qfv.png" height="492" width="720" /
</p>
```

Moodle transforms this into final html:

```
<p>
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://mymoodleserver.com/pluginfile.php/553/mod_lesson/page_contents/1725/sound_card_zpstlml0qfv.png" height="492" width="720" /
</p>
```

I have figured out that @@PLUGINFILE@@ needs to be replaced with the path to the image file but I just don't know what is the first number in the final image URL. I guess it is some ID but I can figure out what. I figured out the second number in the URL is `id` from `lesson_pages` table.

http://mymoodleserver.com/pluginfile.php/SOME_ID/mod_lesson/page_contents/PAGE_ID/image_file.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the first number in the final image URL (553, in your example) an id from mdl_files table?

What I still don't understand is the relationship between the file in the mdl_files table and the actual image file.

Please post the answer, if you found it.

Comment: No the first number is contextid from mdl_files. It's complicated how Moodle handles the files and URLs. I have taken different approach on the end was much easier then figuring out Moodle's image system. I parsed filename from all the <img src=""> tags and l just added reference to my image repository in front of that. Then just copied all Moodle images to my image repository. Hope this helps you...

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you!